# curl formatting in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, unix, curl

I have a curl which works perfectly fine on linux system. I am just remotely triggering a Jenkins job with some parameters.

However the same command in Windows errors out.

```
curl.exe -k --user abc:xyz -X POST https://myjenkins.com/job/abc/buildWithParameters??token=deploy\&release_version=2.3.1.0-5-auto2\&docker_registry=10.0.0.12:8083\&vcmts_build=vcmts_pi07
```

Following is the error:

```
    At line:1 char:260
+ ... ??token=deploy\&release_version=2.3.1.0-5-auto2\&docker_registry=96.118.23.36:80 ...
+                    ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
At line:1 char:293
+ ... .3.1.0-5-auto2\&docker_registry=10.0.0.12:8083\&vcmts_build=vcmts_pi07
+                    ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
At line:1 char:328
+ ... 0.0.12:8083\&vcmts_build=vcmts_pi07
+                    ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double
quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

What is the formatting change should i do to avoid this issue?

Comment: I assume wrap the POST URL in quotes:  `POST "https:...vcmts_pi07"`. Failing this, single quotes:  `POST 'https:...vcmts_pi07'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your arguments in single quotes, which are not expanded like double-quoted strings.

```
curl -k --user 'abc:xyz' -X POST 'https://myjenkins.com/job/abc/buildWithParameters?token=deploy&release_version=2.3.1.0-5-auto2&docker_registry=10.0.0.12:8083&vcmts_build=vcmts_pi07'
```